# How to create a Batch file to restart Zend server

Tags: batch-file, zend-framework

I have a Situation where i usually restarts a Zend server 7-8 times a day. What Steps i follow is I go to Startup Services and Select my Zend Deployment , I right click on it and says Re-start. I am Looking to create a Batch file which i can place on my desktop and double clicking on it will restart my Zend server. Please let me know if its possible to do and if possible how i can achieve this

Below are the reference images of what i am actually talking. Also correct me if am wrong in describing my question or you need additional details.[image]

Comment: I think, `SC /?` is the command, you are looking for.

Comment: @Stephan : I am so Sorry, I am very new and did not have knowledge in creating batch script.

Comment: 1. open command window (`Win`+`R`cmd); 2. `sc` to see help; 3. `sc query state= all` and find your service `keyname`; 4. combine `sc stop ...` and `sc start ...` to restart your service; 5. last succesfull steps [Write to a Batch File](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File); 6. last not least:[learn more](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) (Note: all procedure might ask running with elevated privileges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`NET START` and `NET STOP` commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

```
   REM Stop the service.
   NET STOP "Zend Deployment"

   REM Start the service.
   NET START "Zend Deployment"
```

You would need to run a batch script which uses these commands with elevated permissions.